# MySQL - Left Join takes too long, how to optimize query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join, innodb

A leader may have many followers. A `notification_followers` table gets a single notification when a leader adds a post with an entry `leader_id 1` and `notifiable_id 0` (id 1,2 in table). The same table gets a single notification when the current user `14` is followed by someone, with an entry `leader_id 0` and `notifiable_id 14` (id 3 in table).

`notification_followers` (*id is PRIMARY, each field except data is an index on its own*)

```
| id | uuid               | leader_id | notifable_id | data   | created_at
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 001w2cwfoqzp8F3... | 1         | 0            | Post A | 2018-04-19 00:00:00
| 2  | lvbuX4d5qCHJUIN... | 1         | 0            | Post B | 2018-04-20 00:00:00
| 3  | eEq5r5g5jApkKgd... | 0         | 14           | Follow | 2018-04-21 00:00:00
```

All the follower related notifications are in one place now which is perfect.

We need to now check if the user `14` is a follower of `leader_id 1` to know whether to show them notifications `1` and `2`. For that, we scan the `user_follows` table to see if the logged in user exists as a `followed_id` to the `leader_id` so they know about the notification, but only if they followed the leader **before** the notification was posted (new followers should not get older post notifications when the follow the user, only new ones).

`user_follows` *(id is PRIMARY, each field is an index on its own)*

```
| id | leader_id | follower_id | created_at
----------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1         | 14         |  2018-04-18 00:00:00 // followed before, has notifs
| 2  | 1         | 15         |  2018-04-22 00:00:00 // followed after, no notifs
```

The final thing to note, is the user should know if the notification was read or not, this is where the `notification_followers_read` table comes in. It stores the `follower_id` along with the `notification_uuid` for all read notifications, along with their `read_at` timestamp.

`notification_followers_read` *(composite index on notification_uuid, follower_id)*

```
| notification_uuid | follower_id | read_at
--------------------------------------------------------
  qIXE97AP49muZf... | 17          | 2018-04-21 00:00:00 // not for 14, we ignore it
```

We now want to return the latest 10 notifications ordered by the auto incrementing `nf.id` desc for user `14`. They should see all 3 notifications from `notification_followers`, since **non of them were read by this user yet**. The first 2, since they followed the leader **before** the leader made the posts, and the 3rd notification, since they were followed and their `notifiable_id` is `14`.

Here is the query which works, but take too long **~9 secs**:

```
SELECT nf.id, nf.uuid, nf.leader_id, nf.data, nf.created_at, nfr.read_at
FROM notification_followers nf
LEFT JOIN user_follows uf ON uf.leader_id = nf.leader_id AND uf.follower_id = 14
LEFT JOIN notification_followers_read nfr ON nf.uuid = nfr.notification_uuid AND nfr.follower_id = 14
WHERE (nf.created_at > uf.created_at OR notifiable_id = 14)
ORDER BY nf.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

`notification_followers` has ~100K records and we're using InnoDB. Here is the `EXPLAIN` for the query:

[image: Explain]

How can we optimize the query so it runs in a few ms?

**UPDATE with UNION**

Below is the `EXPLAIN` for the following `UNION` query, and I also included the `EXPLAIN`for each subquery by itself respectively.

```
(SELECT nf.id, nf.uuid, nf.leader_id, nf.data, nf.created_at, nfr.read_at
FROM notification_followers nf
LEFT JOIN user_follows uf ON uf.leader_id = nf.leader_id AND uf.follower_id = 14 AND nf.created_at > uf.created_at
LEFT JOIN notification_followers_read nfr ON nf.uuid = nfr.notification_uuid AND nfr.follower_id = 14
ORDER BY nf.id DESC
LIMIT 10)

UNION DISTINCT

(SELECT nf.id, nf.uuid, nf.leader_id, nf.data, nf.created_at, nfr.read_at
FROM notification_followers nf
LEFT JOIN notification_followers_read nfr ON nf.uuid = nfr.notification_uuid AND nfr.follower_id = 14
WHERE nf.notifiable_id = 14
ORDER BY nf.id DESC
LIMIT 10)

ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 10
```

[image]

**UPDATE WITH SQL DUMP**

[SQL DUMP TO REPRODUCE LOCALLY](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZktZNgM5CMfXVxp8Kjn_V7GfvErDujtx/view?usp=sharing) just create `speed_test` database locally and import file to see the slow query issue live with all the table data *(~100K rows)*.

Comment: Why is `LEFT JOIN user_follows uf ON uf.leader_id = nf.leader_id AND uf.follower_id = 14` in the query?

Comment: `14` is the currently logged in user in this case. In `user_follows` table they are `follower_id` to identify them with the `leader_id` there. In `notification_followers_read` table they are `follower_id` to identify them with the `notification_uuid`. In `notification_followers` they are `notifiable_id` only when a user follows them, not a new leader post, so we can identify that they were followed.

Comment: I meant in the sense that nothing is selected from `user_follows`, nor is it used to filter results in any manner. Since it is LEFT JOINed to `nf`, it will not affect the data drawn from it; and it is not used to reduce the data from `nfr`.

Comment: When you're using `LEFT JOIN`, conditions on the second table should almost always be in `ON` rather than `WHERE`. If you put it in `WHERE`, you'll filter out the null rows when there's no match.

Comment: @Uueerdo He's filtering with `nf.created_at > uf_created_at`.

Comment: @Barmar oh, completely overlooked that for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is:

```
SELECT nf.id, nf.uuid, nf.leader_id, nf.data, nf.created_at, nfr.read_at
FROM notification_followers nf LEFT JOIN
     user_follows uf
     ON uf.leader_id = nf.leader_id AND uf.follower_id = 14 LEFT JOIN
     notification_followers_read nfr
     ON nf.uuid = nfr.notification_uuid AND nfr.follower_id = 14
WHERE nf.created_at > uf.created_at OR nf.notifiable_id = 14
ORDER BY nf.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This is a bit hard.  The `or` clause is a real killer.  But  based on your logic, I think you want more of an `and` than an `or`:

```
SELECT nf.id, nf.uuid, nf.leader_id, nf.data, nf.created_at, nfr.read_at
FROM notification_followers nf LEFT JOIN
     user_follows uf
     ON uf.leader_id = nf.leader_id AND nf.created_at > uf.created_at AND 
        uf.follower_id = 14 LEFT JOIN
     notification_followers_read nfr
     ON nf.uuid = nfr.notification_uuid AND nfr.follower_id = 14
WHERE nf.notifiable_id = 14
ORDER BY nf.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

(Note that it moves to the `ON` clause.)

The obvious indexes are:  `notification_followers(notifiable_id, leader_id, created_at)`, `user_follows(leader_id, follower_id, created_at)` and `notification_followers_read(notification_uuid, notifiable_id)`.

Comment: So the issue with the proposed query is it only searches for `notifiable_id` = `14`, which is when a user is followed. What it's missing in the results, is when a leader posts a new post and the current user is a follower of them (followed them before they added the post, they should be notified), which user `14` (`follower_id`) is following leader posts does not get returned.

Comment: I think he really did want `OR`. Which probably means that the best way to solve this is to split this into two queries, combined with `UNION`.

Comment: @Barmar can you show how you think `UNION` would solve it? The issue is just that it takes too long atm to return the notifications, even though the results are correct.

Comment: @Wonka `OR` conditions make it hard for MySQL to use indexes, that's why the query takes so long. Write one query for `notifiable_id = 14`, and another query for `nf.created_at > uf.created_at`. They should each run quickly, then you combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: @Barmar wasn't able to get the 2 queries to run with `UNION` as I got `Table 'nf' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in field list` btw, without the `UNION` and without the `OR` the query with `nf.created_at > uf.created_at` takes ~6-7 secs, where as, the `notifiable_id = 14` takes a few ms. But the issue with this approach is I am trying to get the latest 10 items, whether they are new leader post or current user being followed. With separating the queries, I feel like it may not be the combination of latest items correctly, and may be scattered results of leader posts vs followed user.

Comment: @Wonka Both queries should start with `FROM notification_followers nf`, so I'm not sure why you got that error. And you can do `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10` on the result of the union to get the latest items from the combination.

Comment: @Wonka I'll try writing an answer.

Comment: @Barmar . . . I think he wants one condition in the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN` and the other in the `WHERE`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff See my answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff My answer has the correct logic, but he's still having trouble getting good performance on the first subquery in the union. If you can figure out what indexes he needs to fix that up, it would be super.

Comment: I added an **UPDATE WITH SQL DUMP** section for easy local reproduction as well to see it locally

Answer (score 0):

`OR` often causes performance problems because it makes it difficult to use an index. Split the query into the two different cases, and combine them with `UNION`.

```
(SELECT nf.id, nf.uuid, nf.leader_id, nf.data, nf.created_at, nfr.read_at
FROM notification_followers nf
LEFT JOIN user_follows uf ON uf.leader_id = nf.leader_id AND uf.follower_id = 14 AND nf.created_at > uf.created_at
LEFT JOIN notification_followers_read nfr ON nf.uuid = nfr.notification_uuid AND nfr.follower_id = 14
ORDER BY nf.id DESC
LIMIT 10)

UNION ALL

(SELECT nf.id, nf.uuid, nf.leader_id, nf.data, nf.created_at, nfr.read_at
FROM notification_followers nf
LEFT JOIN notification_followers_read nfr ON nf.uuid = nfr.notification_uuid AND nfr.follower_id = 14
WHERE nf.notifiable_id = 14
ORDER BY nf.id DESC
LIMIT 10)

ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Hmmm... It still took ~7-8 secs (also, the `nf.notifiable_id = 14` result showed up twice in the result set, can tell by duplicated `nf.id` in results)

Comment: @Wonka Use `UNION DISTINCT` instead of `UNION ALL` to remove duplicates. Do you have all the necessary indexes? Also, are you sure you need `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`? `INNER JOIN` is generally faster.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` on each subquery to see how they're being optimized.

Comment: I added an update to the question with the `Explain` section. The indexes are the same ones set on the original question in parenthesis next to the table name `table_name (indexes)`. I tried `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` but I didn't get the results, so seems like I can't use an inner join. I think the indexes are correct, but not sure how to speed it up. Been on this for a few days but still can't figure it out...

Comment: Since you're joining on multiple columns, you probably need a multi-column index to improve that, the single-column indexes aren't enough.

Comment: Which indexes do you suggest be used on the tables as opposed to the current?

Comment: Maybe something like `user_follows (leader_id, follower_id, created_at)` and `notification_followers_read (uuid, follower_id)`

Comment: BTW, except for performance, is this returning the correct result? Don't want to waste time optimizing a wrong query.

Comment: Yup, the query returns the correct results, so it's just performance. I added the suggested multi-column index's and now the results take ~5-6 secs. Still can't get it lower to the desired ms, I really can't figure out why it takes that long though with the correct indexes too!

Comment: Might need to add the 3-column index to `notification_followers` as well.

Comment: I added a 4-column index for `notification_followers (uuid, leader_id, notifiable_id, created_at)` but the timing is still ~5-6. BTW, it seems `EXPLAIN` lists the multi column index under `possible_keys` but `key` is always null, meaning it's not using it I think. The bottleneck is the first query, as the second one only takes ms to run.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: No worries, thank you for helping out so far, I really appreciate your help Barmar. I'll have to keep at it, at least we know it's one query causing the issue.

Comment: Hmmm... It seems the `ORDER BY nf.id DESC` is what is slowing it down to ~5 secs, without it, the single bottle neck query is a few ms. Any idea about proceeding now that we narrowed it down to the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: What happens if you leave the `ORDER BY` out of the subquery, but keep it in the outer query?

Comment: So removing the `ORDER BY` out of the subqueries, and leaving it in the outer query returns results with ids `100001, 11-3` where `100001` is followed notification, and `11-3` are new leader post notification. So the `11-3` results order is not correct. But leaving the query as is, the results are correct `100001 - 99992` but it's the performance issue. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep at it.

Comment: What is `11-3`? Isn't `nf.id` an integer in both subqueries?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the range of `11` to `3`, `11, 10, 9, ..., 4, 3`

Comment: Did you leave `LIMIT 10` in the subqueries? The limit is only useful when combined with ordering. Otherwise you're just picking a random set of 10 rows.

Comment: I tried with and without the `LIMIT 10` in subqueries but either the results ordering are not correct, (`ORDER BY nf.id DESC`), or they are correct but take ~5 secs. I am starting to think the issue is not having a descending index, (which I don't think is possible before `mysql 8.0`). Atm I am on `mysql 5.7.22` This covers it more https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/20/mysql-8-0-descending-indexes-can-speedup-your-queries/

Comment: I tried the negative index trick mentioned in the article but it still takes just as long. I think I am just going to give up on this one :/

Comment: I added an **UPDATE WITH SQL DUMP** section for easy local reproduction as well to see it locally

Answer (score 0):

I used the dump file you provided to reproduce this environment on my pc. The original query's execution duration was originally 0.8 seconds, without any schema changes. Maybe the time difference is because my database is running on an SSD?

Anyway, when adding the following indexes, the execution duration reduced to 50ms.

```
ALTER TABLE `notification_followers` ADD INDEX `notification_followe_idx_id_uuid_at_id_data` (`leader_id`,`uuid`,`created_at`,`id`,`data`(255));
ALTER TABLE `notification_followers_read` ADD INDEX `notification_followe_idx_id_uuid_at` (`follower_id`,`notification_uuid`,`read_at`);
ALTER TABLE `user_follows` ADD INDEX `user_follows_idx_id_id_at` (`follower_id`,`leader_id`,`created_at`);
```